# How to use `PlaceHolder` in place of `HtmlTableRow` or `HtmlTableCell`?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I would like to create a user control which contains the following in the ASCX file:

```
...
<tr runat="server" ID="mytr">
    <td runat="server" ID="myCell1"></td>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="myPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    <td runat="server" ID="myCell2"></td>
</tr>
...
```

This generates the following error:

> System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCellCollection must have items of
>   type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell'. 'asp:PlaceHolder' is
>   of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder'.

The reason for the `PlaceHolder` is I would like to dynamically generate that cell (for example choosing between `TD` and `TH`, or choosing whether to create it at all.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or maybe I should just create my own custom control which inherits `HtmlTableCell`?

I have noticed that viewstate for certain table elements are keyed by the ordinal (index into child control collection), which means I also sometimes cannot dynamically generate cells when I would expect to be able to. Is there some general best practice with regards to this?

I have also considered always creating the TD, but just hiding it. The problem is that I use `rowspan` on a previous row, meaning different rows will render different numbers of cells. This is conditional and can change between postbacks (by enabling / disabling a row).

Comment: I would like to understand the cause of this issue - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, my issue was related to a missing/invalid </tr> closing branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by making a simple custom control:

```
public class HtmlTableCellPH : HtmlTableCell
{
    public HtmlTableCellPH()
    {
    }

    public HtmlTableCellPH(string tagName)
        : base(tagName)
    {
    }

    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        this.RenderChildren(writer);
    }
}
```

And now the ascx is:

```
...
<tr runat="server" ID="mytr">
    <td runat="server" ID="myCell1"></td>
    <ns:HtmlTableCellPH runat="server" ID="myPlaceholder"></ns:HtmlTableCellPH>
    <td runat="server" ID="myCell2"></td>
</tr>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ASP.net Table Webcontrol** for creating your table dynamically (if you consider of generating whole table from your code.)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could get around this.

**1.** Remove the `runat="server"` attributes from the `table` and `tr` tags.  The down side to this method is that you won't be able to modify those tags from the server-side.  You will still be able to modify any `td` tags though.

**2.** Generate the entire table dynamically from server-side code.

HTML

```
<table runat="server" id="Table1">
</table>
```

C# Server-side code

```
HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
cell.InnerText = "Text goes here.";
row.Cells.Add(cell);

this.Table1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use when I run into this is to replace the `<tr>` with an `<asp:literal>` and write the HTML for the table row myself.

Example:

```
<asp:literal runat="server" ID="trRow" Mode="PassThrough" />
    <td runat="server" ID="myCell1"></td>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="myPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    <td runat="server" ID="myCell2"></td>
</tr>
```

Then in the code behind

```
Literal trRow = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("trRow");
// ... some code here decides on CSS class I want to use
trRow.Text = string.Format("<tr class=\"{0}\">", strCssClass);
```